# window.screenX and window.screen.availLeft both 0 in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that is meant to resize and reposition the current window when my button is clicked, it is meant to reposition the window on the current monitor that the window is displayed on. It is meant to make the current Chrome window fill the current monitor but without being maximized.

Here's my code:

```
function start(tab) {
    // Type: `(tab: tabs.Tab): void`
    // `tabs.Tab`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab

    chrome.windows.getCurrent( getCurrentWindowCallback );
}

function getCurrentWindowCallback( currentWindow ) {
    // Type: `(window: Window): void`
    // `Window`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window

    if( !'id' in currentWindow ) return;

    var s = window.screen;

    var newState = {
        left: s.availLeft,
        top: s.availTop,
        width: s.width,
        height: s.availHeight,
        state: "normal"
    };

    chrome.windows.update(
        /*windowId:*/ currentWindow.id,
        /*updateInfo: */ newState,
        /*callback: */ null
    );
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( start );
```

However, when I run this the value of `window.screen` always corresponds to the first monitor on my computer, regardless of the screen that the current Chrome browser window is on.

```
{ availLeft: 0, availTop: 0, width: 1920, availHeight: 1170 }
```

The `currentWindow` object is a special Chrome extension API object and does not share the `screen` property that the global `window` object does. I suspect this is because the `window` refers to the hidden window that the Background Script executes in.

Is it possible to get the `screen` object for the current Chrome browser window without needing permission/access to the DOM?

Comment: Do you need to get `window.screen` of current browser window or just the four properties `{ availLeft: 0, availTop: 0, width: 1920, availHeight: 1170 }`? And please be aware In the case of the event page, the value of the current window falls back to the last active window.

Comment: @HaibaraAi Just the properties is fine - I'm after the X and Y coordinates of the current monitor/display in the workspace (so that when my extension action is invoked on the right-hand display my script can identify what screen it's on).

Comment: why not just use `currentWindow.top/left/width/height`? It is the last active window when you click browser action. Sorry but it seems I have not figured out what you want to do... When you are in current window (saying that you are in right monitor), click browser action, then ?

Comment: @HaibaraAi Sorry, I forgot to say that I wanted to resize the Chrome window to fill its current monitor. The `currentWindow` doesn't tell me the width of the screen it's on, and `window.screen` always refers to the first screen on my computer (at `(0,0)`) instead of the current screen.

Answer (score 1):

I worked-around this problem by using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to run a script which copies the `window.screen` object from the current window and passing it back to my script to reposition and resize the window:

```
var getScreenScript = `var screenInfo = {
    screen: {
        availTop   : window.screen.availTop,
        availLeft  : window.screen.availLeft,
        availHeight: window.screen.availHeight,
        availWidth : window.screen.availWidth,
        colorDepth : window.screen.colorDepth,
        height     : window.screen.height,
        left       : window.screen.left,
        orientation: window.screen.orientation,
        pixelDepth : window.screen.pixelDepth,
        top        : window.screen.top,
        width      : window.screen.width
    },
    screenX   : window.screenX,
    screenY   : window.screenY,
    screenLeft: window.screenLeft,
    screenTop : window.screenTop,
}; screenInfo`;

function start(tab) {
    // Type: `(tab: tabs.Tab): void`
    // `tabs.Tab`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab

    if( !'id' in tab ) return;

    // Ensure the `tabId` is set, otherwise I got permissions errors.
    chrome.tabs.executeScript( /*tabId:*/ tab.id, { code: getScreenScript }, getScreenScriptResultCallback );
}

function getScreenScriptResultCallback( args ) {

    var screenInfo = args[0];

    chrome.windows.getCurrent( function(currentWindow) {

        if( !'id' in currentWindow ) return;

        transformWindow( currentWindow, screenInfo );
    } );
}

function transformWindow( currentWindow, screenInfo ) {
    // Type: `(currentWindow: Window, screenInfo: object): void`
    // `Window`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window

    var newState = {
        left  : screenInfo.screen.availLeft, // `availLeft` is the X coordinate of the current screen in the multi-mon workspace.
        top   : screenInfo.screen.availTop,
        width : screenInfo.screen.availWidth,
        height: screenInfo.screen.availHeight,
        state: "normal"
    };

    chrome.windows.update( currentWindow.id, newState, /*callback: */ null );
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( start );
```

Comment: Then in fact you are accessing the DOM of current web page, not the same as you said in the question..

Comment: @HaibaraAi That's my workaround. Ideally there should be a way to get the `screen` object without accessing the page's DOM because `window.screen` is not (information-wise) dependent on the current page at all.

Comment: I don't think so, in a tabbed browser, each tab contains its own window object, `window` is not shared across tabs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: @HaibaraAi Yes, but the content of the `window.screen` object is shared.

Comment: Since background page lives in the extension process, which is different from web page tab process, their `window.screen` content may be different. You can't directly get `window` object of current page from background page, and considering background page have no access to web page DOM, the only way would be use content script, no matter manifest injection or programming injection.